# Yii2: Auto save form on navigate to another tab in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, yii2

I'd say I want to submit each tabs content (form values)  when another tab is selected. That way the user navigate between tabs without having to reload the whole form. And the values are saved even if partially filled to the database

I think this can done using jquery or javascript like clicking on the tab will imitate the clicking on save button simultaneously.

I have also tried this code but it's not working? The id of the tab is #ui-id-3 and id of save button is #save1.

```
<script>
    $('#ui-id-3').click(function(){
    $('#save1').click(); 
    return false;
});
    </script>
```

What I am doing wrong here?

With suggest modification:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function() {
  $("#ui-id-3").click(function(){
    autoSave();
    return false;
  });
});

function autoSave(){
      var formData = $("#w0").serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/hospitalerp/web/index.php?r=daily-ward-entry%2Fcreate",
        data:formData,//only input
        success: function(response){
            $( "#recordID" ).val( response);  
        }
    });


  }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution but you have have to modify according to you needs

**Step one :**

Create a hidden field with for ID field we will store database record Id in it you can `name`/`id` input as recordID so we can reference it in our jQuery Code

```
<input type="hidden" name="recordID" id="recordID" value="0" />
```

**Step two :**

Create a server page which will server for Database Insertion/Updation you can called it **autoSave.php** this page will receive complete form and if `recordID <=0` then it will insert into db and return the newly inserted ID else it will update table `where Id = recordID`

**Step 3 :**

Jquery Code which will call autoSavePage upon Tab Click.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".tabs").click(function(){
    autoSave();
    return false;
  });
});

function autoSave(){
      var formData = $("#formID").serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"autoSave.php",
        data:formData,//only input
        success: function(response){
            $( "#recordID" ).val( response);  
        }
    });
    
            
  }
```

Html Form ID should be formID

```
<form id="formID" method="POST" action="autoSave.php">..
```

This is the idea when ever anyone click on any tab a ajax call will be generate to save the form rest you have to modify according to your code as you have not submitted any code thats why i have make a generic example

Hope this will Help!

Comment: Hi Saquibahmad - I am using Yii2-framework and the default id and action is set like this - `<form id="w0" method="post" action="/hospitalerp/web/index.php?r=daily-ward-entry%2Fcreate">
<input type="hidden" value="MS5QMUZkeV9SbWF7fzdIKgFbPHgDOwMpcmIZYClWOAVpHTNTASkIJQ==" name="_csrf">`

Comment: no problem you can use the framework generated names as you have seen there are only three refrences, id hidden field form action and autosave page these all can be get easily

Comment: Hi Saqibahmad - I have pasted the modified code but it doesn't seems to work. weird!

Comment: what error you received, use firebug to check are your ajax request is going to right url, put an alert box or use firbug to validate are you getting data in formData variable before ajax call then let me know

Comment: I am not getting any error in firebug. How do I create an alter box?

Comment: update autoSave javascript function: add alert(formData) after this line var formData = $("#formID").serialize(); and put another alert in success function like this alert(response);

Comment: is this url accessible through browser /hospitalerp/web/index.php?r=daily-ward-entry%2Fcreate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66790/discussion-between-saqibahmad-and-pawan).

Comment: yes, it is accessible like http://localhost/http://localhost/hospitalerp/web/index.php?r=daily-ward-entry%2Fcreate